Is the unbiased autocovariance sequence truly unbiased?
Most textbook definitions of the sample autocovariance sequences use the statistical mean in their definition. However, what if only the sample mean is known? Is the unbiased sample autocovariance sequence still unbiased?

TL;DR
The unbiased estimate of the autocovariance sequence (ACS) is only unbiased if the statistical mean is known. In fact, as will be shown, the biased estimate of the ACS may actually have less bias in certain cases (generally when the autocorrelation function becomes more delta-like) than the unbiased estimate.
Proof
The unbiased estimate of the ACS is guaranteed to be unbiased if and only if the statistical mean of the random process is known. The true ACS of a WSS process $x\left[ n \right]$ is
\begin{equation}
c_{xx}[k] = E\left\{\left(x\left[n\right]-\mu_{x}\right)^{*}\left(x\left[n+k\right]-\mu_{x}\right)\right\} = r_{xx}[k] - \left\lvert\mu_{x}\right\rvert^{2}
\end{equation}
where $r_{xx}[k]$ is the autocorrelation function.
Let the unbiased estimate be defined as
\begin{equation}
\bar{c}_{xx}\left[ k \right] =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}\left(x\left[n+k\right]-\mu_{x}\right)\left(x\left[ n\right]-\mu_{x}\right)^{*} & 0 \leq k < N-1 \\
\bar{c}^{*}_{xx}\left[ k \right] & -N < k < 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and the biased estimate of the ACS is defined as
\begin{equation}
\hat{c}_{xx}\left[ k \right] =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}\left(x\left[n+k\right]-\mu_{x}\right)\left(x\left[ n\right]-\mu_{x}\right)^{*} & 0 \leq k < N-1 \\
\bar{c}^{*}_{xx}\left[ k \right] & -N < k < 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Taking the expected value of the unbiased estimate, we get
\begin{align}
E\left\{\bar{c}_{xx}\left[ k \right]\right\} &= E\left\{\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}\left(x\left[n+k\right]-\mu_{x}\right)\left(x\left[ n\right]-\mu_{x}\right)^{*}\right\} \\ &= \frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}E\left\{\left(x\left[n+k\right]-\mu_{x}\right)\left(x\left[ n\right]-\mu_{x}\right)^{*}\right\} \\ &= \frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}c_{xx}\left[ k \right] \\ &= c_{xx}[k]
\end{align}
However, lets now plug in the sample mean
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mu}_{x} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]
\end{equation}
for $\mu_{x}$. For simplicity in the calculations, we'll assume white noise. The unbiased estimate then becomes
\begin{equation}
E\left\{\bar{c}_{xx}\left[ k \right]\right\} = E\left\{\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}\left(x\left[n+k\right]-\hat{\mu}_{x}\right)\left(x\left[ n\right]-\hat{\mu}_{x}\right)^{*}\right\}
\end{equation}
Evaluating this, we get
\begin{equation}
E\left\{\bar{c}_{xx}[k]\right\} = \frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}E\left\{x[n+k]x^{*}[n]-\hat{\mu}_{x}x^{*}[n] - \hat{\mu}^{*}_{x}x[n+k] + \hat{\mu}_{x}\hat{\mu}^{*}_{x}\right\}
\end{equation}
Evaluating the first term obviously becomes (for $k = 0$)
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}E\left\{x[n+k]x^{*}[n]\right\} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]x^{*}[n] = \sigma^{2}
\end{equation}
Evaluating the second term gives
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}E\left\{x^{*}[n]\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}x[i]\right\} &= \frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}\sigma^{2}\delta_{i,n} \\ &= \frac{1}{N-k}\sum_{n=0}^{N-k-1}\frac{1}{N}\sigma^{2}\\ &= \frac{\sigma^{2}}{N}
\end{align}
Evaluating the third term also gives $\frac{\sigma^{2}}{N}$. The fourth term is also evaluated to the same. Therefore, the expected value is
\begin{equation}
E\left\{\bar{c}_{xx}[k]\right\} = \sigma^{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)
\end{equation}
This means that the bias for the unbiased sample ACS is
\begin{equation}
\textbf{bias}(\bar{c}_{xx}[k]) = -\frac{\sigma^{2}}{N} \; \forall\, k
\end{equation}
Interestingly, for the biased estimate of the ACS, the term $\frac{\sigma^{2}}{N}$ can be replaced with $\frac{\left(N-k\right)\sigma^{2}}{N^{2}}$. Therefore, the expected value in the biased estimate of the ACS is
\begin{equation}
E\left\{\hat{c}_{xx}[k]\right\} = \sigma^{2}\left(1-\frac{N-\left\lvert k\right\rvert}{N^{2}}\right)
\end{equation}
and the bias is
\begin{equation}
\textbf{bias}(\hat{c}_{xx}[k]) = -\frac{(N-\left\lvert k\right\rvert)\sigma^{2}}{N^{2}} \; \forall\, k
\end{equation}
Since the equations for both $\bar{c}_{xx}[k]$ and $\hat{c}_{xx}[k]$ are only defined for $0 \leq k < N$, the bias in the biased estimate is strictly less $\forall k \neq 0$, and equal for $k=0$. This means that the biased and unbiased estimates produce the same value for lag 0, but different values for all other lags.
Thus, this shows that for ACS estimates where the statistical mean is unknown, the unbiased ACS estimate is likely biased, and the biased estimate of the ACS may actually produce less bias than the unbiased estimate of the ACS.
